# What distribution does “arrival of people” at an event in time follow?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

Suppose that there is a Cricket match scheduled on Sunday, this weekend. We know that people do not arrive at the stadium at constant rate. Few hours before scheduled start of the match, people start arriving at very slow rate. This rate then, in general, keeps on increasing. A large number of people arrive just before start of the match.

I would like to know which distribution should I use to model this, so that I could tell **What is the probability of arrival of x number of people in a particular time interval?**

Comment: Maybe this is relevant to your question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Non-homogeneous

Comment: @RobertSmith - thanks. that was some help. i have just one more question. can I assume the arrival of people at an event to follow exponential distribution. can you provide me some link where i can get some data related to arrival of people, so that i can derive distribution in some way.

Comment: It seems natural to choose a poisson distribution, that is, a scaled exponential distribution, to model arrival of people in a given interval of time. However, since you know that `people do not arrive at the stadium at constant rate` then you can't use a single distribution to model the entire time span. Unfortunately, I don't know of data related to arrival of people to an event. In any case, I suspect the rate would be significantly different in a sport event than in a musical concert, so you need rates suitable to your application.